# Como compartilhar uma propriedade com outros componentes no React?

Tags: aplicação-web, front-end, react

Olá, sou novo no *React* e estou com uma dúvida sobre compartilhamento de propriedades. Por exemplo, eu quero ter um componente pai que terá uma propriedade *"visible"*, e quero compartilhá-la com todos os meus componentes filhos, de modo que eu possa utilizá-la desta forma, por exemplo:

```
CustomInput visible="true";
CustomDropDown visible="false";
```

Gostaria de saber a melhor forma de fazer isso, respeitando as boas práticas.
Agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para passar valores para descendentes deves usar `props`. Para passar todas as `props` de um elemento pai para um descendente podes usar `{...this.props}` nas props do elemento descndente.

Exemplo:

```js
class Pai extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
   Eu sou uma "div". Visivel?: {this.props.visivel ? 'sim' : 'não'}
   <Filho {...this.props}/>
   </div>
  );
 }
}


class Filho extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return <p>Eu sou um "p". Visivel?: {this.props.visivel ? 'sim' : 'não'}</p>;
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Pai visivel={true}/>,
 document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Sergio, funcionou perfeitamente!!!

Comment: @FelipeOliveira ótimo!